# How to justify menu from one edge of container to another

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, justify

How to justify menu blocks (basically bootstrap navbar), when first letter of first item starts from left edge of container and last letter of last item ends on right edge of container?

See example below

[image: example]

Comment: add width 100% in ul

Comment: Flexbox, with justify-content:space-between.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, flexbox is good enough